# Get date from string sqlite without date time

Tags: android, database, string, date, format

I have a table which contains a column that stores dates but in the form of strings and not in date time format.I need to pull out only that values that match the same day and same month as the one i specify.How can this be done?The current format of the string that the date is stored in is like this 2015-12-30.
So if i wanted all the dates that match 30th of december irrespective of year this date should be in the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this question is related to `Java Strings` and solution is also present only there you can `split` the string as-

```
String string = "2004-12-23";
String[] parts = string.split("-");
String part1 = parts[0]; // 2004
String part2 = parts[1]; // 12
String part3 = parts[2]; // 23
```

then match day with part3 and match month with part 2 and that's it.